# Clear notifications everywhere in one go

Tags: feature-request

I would like an adjustment in the way notifications are handled. Currently I have the "remove" a notification atleast twice to clear it.

Once at the top by clicking the icon for `Recent achievements: reputation, badges, and privileges earned` to clear that button and then after I have to visit my profile page and click the affected tabs to clear the message there.

I also noticed that if I see the notification at the top on my phone first and clear it, I can still see it on my desktop. It's been a while since this happend, so this might be fixed already.

I know it's a small burden, but it still bothers me for quite a while now.

I would like a notifications to be cleared on all pages when it is viewed at a single page or when the affected page is visited. EG: I visit my own question and all notifications about up/down votes and added comments/answers are cleared.

The last thing would be particularly nice on meta, because I often check on questions/answers I submitted, but if I then browse to my meta profile, I still see notifications of comments I already read.